# jQuery UI dialog content width doesn't change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery UI dialog and I have managed to change the width of the container (outer box) however the content within it seems to be fixed:

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="dialog" width="500px" title="Animal" style="display:none">

<center>

<input type="text" class="input" />
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  </center>
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
function check_domain_input()
    {        
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog({

        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        width:'800',
        height:'500'

        }); 



        $("#dialog").css("width", "260px");

        var domain_val = document.getElementsByName('domain');

        if (domain_val[0].value.length > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        $( "#dialog" ).dialog({modal: true});


        return false;
    }
```

[image: Here is a screenshot of how it looks]

**Need help with getting the content to fit in the whole box**

Notice the scrollbar, that is the size of the content... it does not go past this point

Comment: Remove `$("#dialog").css("width", "260px");` and all set!

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Ryman : can you share the fiddle??

Comment: you should use `$( "#dialog" ).dialog( "option", "width", 260 );`

Answer (score 3):

just remove width from here

```
function check_domain_input()
    {        
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog({

        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        width:'800',//remove this 
        height:'500'

        });
```

and here you can set width according to your requirement using !important do like this

```
<div id="dialog" width="300px !important" title="Animal" style="display:none">
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `$("#dialog").css("width", "260px")` from your script, as it will set the dialog div width fixed to `260px`

Why?

because Your `<div id="dialog"></div>` will have width of `260px` which is your body of a dialog and you're already setting your dialog `height` and `width` so no need to provide width and height property to `$("#dialog")`

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
   resizable: false,
   modal: true,
   width: '800', // Width already defined of dialog
   height: '500' // Height already defined of dialog
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ynr8v/1/)

Answer (score 0):

try so:

```
function check_domain_input()
    {        
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            width:'800',
            height:'500'
        }); 

        //$("#dialog").css("width", "260px");   <-- you can't just change the dialog width
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "option", "width", 260 );   // you should use the proper function

        var domain_val = document.getElementsByName('domain');

        if (domain_val[0].value.length > 0){
            return true;
        }

        $( "#dialog" ).dialog({modal: true});

        return false;
    }
```

You can't only resize the `dialog` element, because when you call the dialog function jQuery build it's dialog element based on your `div`, so you must call the provided method to properly resize the dialog